Wine in installed on Ubuntu, but the system can't find it - what should I do?
I have am using a development version of wine (wine-staging 9.21) for audio production. However, the software I am using can't seem to find wine. This was the particular error I had:
$ yabridgectl sync
Setting up VST2, VST3, and CLAP plugins using:
- /home/alex/.local/share/yabridge/libyabridge-chainloader-vst2.so
- /home/alex/.local/share/yabridge/libyabridge-chainloader-vst3.so
- /home/alex/.local/share/yabridge/libyabridge-chainloader-clap.so

Finished setting up 8 plugins (8 new), skipped 0 non-plugin .dll files
Error: Could not run 'wine', make sure Wine is installed

Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)

System info: Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS, running on a Dell XPS 15 7590.
I have previously been using the up-to-date development version, but due to some issues, I need to downgrade from v10 to v9.21. I did this downgrade via
$ sudo apt-get install wine-staging-i386=9.21~noble-1 wine-staging-amd64=9.21~noble-1
$ sudo apt-get install wine-staging=9.21~noble-1

When I run whereis, I can find it
$ whereis wine
wine: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine /usr/lib/wine /usr/share/wine /opt/wine-staging/bin/wine

When I just run wine in the command line, the computer can't find it - it's looking in a place where it doesn't exist.
$ wine --version
bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
$ ls /usr/bin/wi*
/usr/bin/winicontopam  /usr/bin/winicontoppm  /usr/bin/wireplumber  /usr/bin/wish  /usr/bin/wish8.6

It appears the /opt location is where it actually exists:
$ /opt/wine-staging/bin/wine --version
wine-9.21 (Staging)

What should I do? Is there something I should have specified in the apt-get? Just add a sym-link?

/usr/bin/wine is missing, it should be a link to /etc/alternatives/wine which is a link to /usr/bin/wine-stable.  Do you have other /usr/bin/wine... files to use as a target for the links?

Hi @ubfan1, thanks for your response. I don't have any other wine files is /usr/bin/.

You can try to just add the symlink ln -s /opt/wine-staging/bin/wine /bin/wine or add the /opt/wine-staging/bin to your PATH beginning (if other wine... programs are there) in your .profile where other PATH modifications are made.

Thank you. The symlink suggestion to /usr/bin/wine worked perfectly. If you'd like to make that an answer, I will accept it.

You can answer your own question and accept it after a bit, helping others and gaining some reputation points in the process.

I added a symbolic link to /usr/bin/wine and it now works. Thanks to @ubfan1 for the suggestion.
$ sudo ln -s /opt/wine-staging/bin/wine /usr/bin/wine

